# When I click on the edit button, I need the form to appear inside the card body (replacing the image and all the text)

Tags: javascript, laravel, frontend, onclick

I have cards on my homepage. On hover edit and delete buttons appear. When I click the edit button, a form should appear inside the card I am clicking.

```
                @foreach ($projects as $project)
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 cards marketing">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <a href="{{ $project->url }}">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ $project->image }}" alt="Card image cap" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5>{{ $project->title }}</h5>
                                <p class="card-title">{{ $project->subtitle }}</p>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ $project->description }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-buttons">
                                <a href="#" class="edit-btn" onclick="toggleForm({{ $project->id }})"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a>
                                <form action="{{ route('deleteProject', ['id' => $project->id]) }}" method="POST" class="formDelete">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('DELETE')
                                    <button type="submit" class="btnDelete"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="card-form card-hidden" id="form-{{ $project->id }}">
                            <form action="{{ route('updateProject', ['id' => $project->id]) }}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('PATCH')
                                <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $project->title }}">
                                <button type="submit">Save</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

```
const editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-btn');

editButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const cardContent = this.closest('.card-content');

        // Toggle visibility of card content and form
        cardContent.classList.toggle('card-hidden');
        cardContent.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('card-hidden');
    });
});
```

I was expecting the below result

[[The result should be this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it0Df.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU3ul.png)

Comment: and what is the result you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting anything. I am clicking on the edit button but nothing happens, and I am not seeing any errors in the console.

Comment: what is `editButtons` - you forgot to include the code for that

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it. It is const editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-btn');

Comment: Please use the console or alert to check which line it is working.  I can assume If your cards are appending using js then you should try this one : 

```const editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('body .edit-btn');```